# making a grid system in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to make something like this image in bootstrap 5 .
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46aXy.png)

also I want to add image inside every three of them . How can I Do this with the bootstrap grid system?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the raw Bootstrap flex box based layout for your design:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row flex-column">
       <div>
        <img>
       </div>
       <div>
        <img>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```